# Arduino Ethercard - return content of website

Tags: c, arduino

I am trying to access a website, and then return whatever it outputs in the body -> eg. "Success" or "Failed".

When I try with my code, I am getting the following back.

```
<<< REQ >>>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 30 Aug 2014 17:36:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d8a4fc3c84849b6786c6ca890b92e2cc01409420191023; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.japseyz.com; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
Server.
```

My code is: http://pastebin.com/WwWbnLNn

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is whether the HTTP transaction succeeded or failed, then you need to examine the HTTP Response code... which is in the first line of the response.  In your example it is "200"... the human readable interpretation of it is "OK".

Here is a link to most of the HTTP 1.1 response codes: [w3.org-rfc2616 RespCodes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Your question indicated you wanted to extract this information from the "body"...
... but that information is not located in the "body", it is in the first response
header, as described above.

Comment: Oh no, Not the response header, but some custom output text. "Success" was just an example.

EG. Example.com/cal/insert?time=0000:00:00&title=Test
If this succeeds, it might output "Successfully entered $title", and if not it might output "Sorry, can't create the calendar event".

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ethercard samples? there is a webclient sample, in which you can find procedure called CALLBACK - in that procedure you can process data stored in buf variable.

in your case you need to look for first empty line, which tells you that headers has been sent and page content(what php writes to the page i.e.) follows.

how familiar are you at pointers? how deep you do need to process the page output? i.e. OK or ERROR is enough, or you do need to pass same parameters back to duino?